# Azure B2C login with Cypress oauth 2.0 - {tenant}.b2clogin.com

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, cypress, azure-ad-b2c, cypress-login

I am currently trying to implement a Cypress e2e test which is involving Azure B2C AD as external identity provider.
So first I tried to visit the login page just as a normal user would, with:

```
cy.get('#loginButton').click();
// this will visit: 
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...
cy.wait(2000);
cy.get('input').first().type(email).should('have.value', email);
cy.get('[id="password"]').type(password).should('have.value', password);
cy.get('#next').click();
// should now redirect me to my app with the access token in my local storage
```

But then i get the following error:

```
{statusCode: 401, message: "Unauthorized"}
```

While doing it myself inside the browser works perfectly fine. Cypress cannot do it. Then I learned, that Cypress cannot accept state from external websites and I need to get the login token with cy.request() and inject it in my application:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1342

[Tutorial: Azure AD Authentication in Cypress Tests with MSAL](https://blog.mechanicalrock.io/2022/08/08/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html)

[Example Code](https://github.com/MechanicalRock/cypress-msal-demo/blob/main/cypress/support/commands.ts)

The Problem here is, that they used:

> `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${Cypress.env('AZURE_TENANT_ID')}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

but my app uses:

> `https://${Cypress.env('AZURE_TENANT_NAME')}.b2clogin.com/${Cypress.env('AZURE_TENANT_NAME')}.onmicrosoft.com/${Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_LOGIN_POLICY_NAME')}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

I tried to adapt the tutorial request, but it does not work for me:

```
  Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {    
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://${Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_AUTH_TENANT')}.b2clogin.com/${Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_AUTH_TENANT')}.onmicrosoft.com/${Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_AUTH_LOGIN_POLICY_NAME')}/oauth2/v2.0/Token`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: `${Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_AUTH_CLIENT_ID')}`,
        client_secret: Cypress.env('AZURE_AD_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        scope: 'openid%20offline_access',
        username: Cypress.env('AZURE_USERNAME'),
        password: Cypress.env('AZURE_PASSWORD')
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      injectTokens(response);
    });
```

This request yields:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid offline_access' provided in request must specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.\r\nCorrelation ID: 147e543e-7b12-4349-8917-ad7d97b4b7cd\r\nTimestamp: 2022-12-08 11:40:05Z\r\n"
}
```

Sadly I have no clue what this error means, which URL need i to provide? Which is the permission a user has to login to the website? I just want the token so i can visit the website as authentificated user with Cypress.

I know here are some posts with suggestions on how to approach this, but no a single one works for my url, with the ".b2clogin.com" inside, this works diffrent i guess.

Here are the 3 exposed urls i can call:

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{loginPolicy}/SelfAsserted
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{loginPolicy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one web application in my B2C tenant and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In Manifest, make sure to enable **implicit flow** like below:

[image]

Now, I created one **resource owner user flow** like below:

[image]

When I tried to get the token giving **same parameters** via Postman, I got **same error** as you like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenantname.b2clogin.com/b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<ROPC_policyname>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<App_ID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:openid offline_access
username:<UPN_of_B2C user> 
password:xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to include your **Application ID** in `scope` parameter.

I generated the tokens successfully by changing **scope** like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenantname.b2clogin.com/b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<ROPC_policyname>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<App_ID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:openid <App_ID> offline_access
username:<UPN_of_B2C user> 
password:xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you want to get both **access** and **id tokens**, then include `response_type` parameter like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenantname.b2clogin.com/b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<ROPC_policyname>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<App_ID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:openid <App_ID> offline_access
response_type: token id_token
username:<UPN_of_B2C user> 
password:xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your scenario, change value of **`scope`** parameter in your code by including your **Application ID** along with *openid* and *offline_access*.

**Reference:**

[Set up a resource owner password credentials flow - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow#test-the-ropc-flow)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Your tip with the response_type to also get the id_token was really helpful.

I created a new flow for ROPC and i was able to reproduce your example. But, the token i get with the ROPC flow was not compatible with my app. Examinig the JWT i get with the ROPC response, I saw it is missing some parameters. I added them by selecting the checkboxes under "Azure AD B2C | User Flows". After this i could finally use the id_token to get a active session for my client. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is what Stack Overflow is all about.  This INCREDIBLY detailed answer finally solved an issue we've been chasing down for days.  Thank you @sridevi !